# django UniqueConstraint inherited tables

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        constraints = [ models.UniqueConstraint(fields=("field1", "field2", "field3"), name='unique_stuff'), ]

class Child1(Parent):
    pass

class Child2(Parent):
    pass
```

This will do a `makemigrations` ok but then fail to `migrate`, at least in Django 2.2. You have to provide a name (Django doesn't seem to want to auto-generate one). Is the only way to achieve this to have a `Meta` class in each child class and have a separately named constraint in each? Could I try and use some kind of name based on the type of the child class? What would be the most DRY way to do this?

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: (Sorry, missed your question)
PostgreSQL 10